# Difference in legend position between ggplot and ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggplotly

I find out an interesting and strange difference between the same chart in ggplot and ggplotly

```
income_gap_chart <- ggplot(income_gap, aes(x = Country, y = Percent, fill = Income)) + 
geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
coord_flip() +
theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
theme_tufte() +
theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

For ggplot it looks perfect with a legend title at the bottom

[image]

But when I wrap this with ggplotly(), the legend starts to behave differently

[image]

My problem - I want the first chart in ggplotly format, but cannot fix this issue and legend at the bottom does not work. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be an open issue: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1049

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Resolved pretty fast with the help of some R experts.

Added this

```
ggplotly(income_gap_chart) %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2))
```

Result:[image]

Thanks!

Comment: There's no legend title in this solution

Comment: @PoGibas, if somebody can add another solution - great! I got the desired result

Comment: I get error: `Error in layout(., legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2)) : 
  unused argument (legend = list(orientation = "h", x = 0.4, y = -0.2))`

Comment: @PeyM87, thanks, sorry for to hear this. I did not touch that code for more than 1 year, so maybe they updated something since then, cannot guarantee for sure it works now. Check the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The solution seemed to drop the legend title as pointed out in the comments. This was easy to fix by including `title = ...` inside `layout()`:

```
diamonds_chart <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = carat, fill = color)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
  
diamonds_chart %>% 
  ggplotly %>% 
  layout(
    legend = list(
      orientation = 'h', x = 0.3, y = -0.1, 
      title = list(text = 'My legend title')
      )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question 3 years ago. Hopefully they improved things since!