# Plotly resets legend and makes ggplot2 blurred

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am trying to use ggplotly on my ggplot2 plot to get the nice hover addon that comes with ggplotly. When using ggplotly, my ggplot2 becomes blurry and resets my legend theme options. How can i avoid this? Or isn't it possible to get exact same ggplot2 plot using ggplotly?

Plot using ggplotly

```
   mc_plotly <- mc_plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = CounterpartyName, y = value, fill = MarginCallType)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge", color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#112b4d","#e4b9d4")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Margin call", labels = comma) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())

ggplotly(mc_plotly) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

And the difference in the plots:

[image: ggplot2 plot]

[image: ggplotly plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in legend position between ggplot and ggplotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54451001/difference-in-legend-position-between-ggplot-and-ggplotly)

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?